# Hide specific element when hover over a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have a shopping bag icon under my posts(.wrap-front-page-shop) and I am trying to make it so that when you hover over the shopping bag icon the post excerpt will disappear(.front-page-post-excerpt).  I'm trying to do this with css, and I think I have written the css right, but it is not working. Does anyone see my mistake, or is there a better way to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

the css

```html
.wrap-front-page-shop:not(:hover) .front-page-post-excerpt {
   font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 50px 50px;
        display: block;
  position:absolute;
}
.wrap-front-page-shop:hover .front-page-post-excerpt {
    color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

front-page-shop-the-post.php (the code is for the shopping icon and the actual shopping widget that shows up when you hover over the shopping icon - it works correctly)

```html
<div class="wrap-front-page-shop">
        <div class="front-page-shop-image"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/shopping-shopping-bag-icon.png" /></div>
    <div class="shopthepost-widget-front">
<?php if (shortcode_exists('show_shopthepost_widget')) {

    // Get the value of the custom field defined in the editor
    $widgetId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_id', true);

    // Check if a value is set
    if (!empty($widgetId)) {

        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="'.$widgetId.'"]';

    } else {

        // or use a default widget
        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="2379026"]';
    }

    echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
} ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css to show the shopping widget when you hover over shopping icon)

```html
.wrap-front-page-shop:not(:hover) .shopthepost-widget-front {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
  position:absolute;
}
.wrap-front-page-shop:hover .shopthepost-widget-front {
    display: block;
  position:absolute;
        margin-left:-225px;
    bottom:150px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    padding:30px;
}
.wrap-front-page-shop:hover .stp-control {
background-color: #ffffff !important;
          display:inherit !important;
}
.wrap-front-page-shop {
    display: inline-block;
}
.front-page-shop-image {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

font-page.php that shows post excerpt code

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <div class="large-front-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                </div>
               <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-page-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </div>
            </article>
<?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-page-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </div>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

JS I tried adding in for a possible solutions (did not work)

```js
var _products = document.getElementById("front-page-shop-image"),
  _hideIfHovered = document.getElementById("front-page-post-excerpt");

for (var i=0, e = _products.children; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].onmouseenter = function() {
    _hideIfHovered.style.display = "none"; 
  }
  
  e[i].onmouseleave = function() {
    _hideIfHovered.style.display = "inherit"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the html code?

Comment: As an aside, why are you setting the colour of a hidden element?

Comment: What html code do you need? My front page? - I was seeing if I could at least get the text color to be white since the excerpt was not disappearing.

Comment: The CSS shown works if `.front-page-post-excerpt` is a descendant of `.wrap-front-page-shop`: https://jsfiddle.net/c3ht6879/

Comment: .front-page-post-excerpt is not a descendant of .wrap-front-page-shop they are both two different elements from two different php files. Is there some other way I could write the code so that .front-page-post-excerpt doesn't have to be a descendant of .wrap-front-page-shop to get it to work?

Comment: Doing it via CSS is only reasonable if there is a structural connection between the elements, so could also be done if they were siblings or something. Otherwise, it can be done easily enough with a few lines of JavaScript/jQuery. Is there only one of each element on the page?

Comment: The page is the front page of my website. It lists all of the posts of the site. Under each post there is a different shopping widget and a different post excerpt.